# java dice game, im a beginner in java and struggling .. any suggestions would be nice

Tags: java, dice

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class diceGame { 
public static void main(String[] arg) {

  int alydarPace;
  int affirmedPace;

  boolean wantsToPlay = true;

  ImageIcon INPUTPIC = new ImageIcon("INPUTPIC.jpg");

  while(wantsToPlay == true){ 
  JOptionPane.messageDialog(null,"Welcome to watch the greatest rivalry in horse racing history... Affirmed vs Alydar.", "", 0, INPUTPIC);

   { 
   int alydarPace; alydarPace = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
   int affirmedPace; affirmedPace = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);

  if (alydarPace > affirmedPace) {

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "And away they go with Alydar taking the Lead!", "", 0, INPUTPIC);
```

}  else if (alydarPace < affirmedPace) {

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "And away they go with Affirmed taking the Lead!", "", 0, INPUTPIC);
```

}  else if (alydarPace = affirmedPace) {

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "And away they go with both horses evenly running neck and neck!", "", 0, ChildSpainFlag);
```

}

int alydarPace; alydarPace = (int)(Math.random()*6+1) + alydarPace;
  int affirmedPace; affirmedPace = (int)(Math.random()*6+1) + affirmedPace;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Down the stretch they come and the winner is Alydar!", "", 0, INPUTPIC);

}  else if (alydarPace < affirmedPace) {

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Down the stretch they come and the winner is Affirmed!", "", 0, INPUTPIC);
```

}  else if (alydarPace = affirmedPace) {

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Down the stretch they come.. is a photo finish and the horses have tied!", "", 0, INPUTPIC);
```

}

int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?");

```
if(answer != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
  wantsToPlay = false;
} else {
  System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Suggestion: scrap this code and start over, but this time concentrate on using a better coding heuristic. You're adding a whole lot of code all at once without checking as you're going, leaving you with a rat's nest of errors. Instead either use an IDE that marks your compilation errors immediately, or else compile your code often, perhaps after every 1 to 2 new lines, and most important **don't add any new code to your project until the current compiles.** Else you'll end up with, well you'll end up with *this*.

Comment: thanks for the quick response I will try again. I do not know what ya mean by heuristic and is there a certain class or object that would make this easier for me?

Comment: I mean your method of creating code. Your current method appears to be to type it in all at once without checking, and that's a bad thing to do. Instead start with the barest skeleton of a class, compile, correct, and add more code. Then keep doing this: add a line or two of code, compile, test, correct before adding more code.

Comment: Previous comments standing as they are, I suspect your problem is that you have `=` in your `if` statements instead of `==`.

Comment: Ian thank you very much!  seems like I need to be more detailed and go over each line.. also I am going to try netbeans instead of jgrasp to try and catch errors.

Comment: thanks a bunch guys.. I changed the = to == and got rid of the boolean at end and changed the loop process with ifwantstoplay again and it works perfect.. what a great site.. really hope one day I can help other like you guys do ... really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you have is a bit of a mess, I suspect that your actual problem is that you're using an assignment operator (`=`) where you actually need a comparison operator (`==`).

It's a classic beginner's trap in Java (and other languages, too, for that matter).  The single equals sign means take the variable to the left of the sign, and assign it the value you get by evaluating the right side of the sign.

```
a = b + 3
```

Would assign the value `b + 3` to `a`.

The *double* equals sign means to compare the two values.

```
a == b + 3
```

Asks the question "is `a` 3 more than `b`".

Inside an `if` statement's condition in Java, you are required to ask such a question (you need a `boolean`).  The error message you should get from using the wrong one would be something like "Cannot convert from int to boolean."